# Why is hardhat contract deployment script consuming high gas?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, erc-721, hardhat-deploy

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
async function main(file_name, private_key, smart_contract_name, smart_contract_symbol) {
const networkURL = hre.network.config.url;
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(networkURL);
const feeData = await provider.getFeeData();
console.log("feeData obj :",feeData);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(private_key , provider);
const contract = await hre.ethers.deployContract(file_name, [smart_contract_name,smart_contract_symbol],{ signer });
await contract.waitForDeployment();
console.log(contract.target);
return contract.target;
}
        
main("CoolNFT","myprivatekey","SmartContractName","SmartContractSymbol")
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch(error => {
console.error(error);
process.exit(1);
});
```

I have this hardhat smart contract deployment script . With the help of NodeJS child process and hardhat , I am developing a token deployment app ( ERC721 ). main function takes 4 parameters i.e. file_name , private_key , smart_contract_name , smart_contract_symbol . Now , the app is working perfectly but the contract deployment cost is more than it should be .

Problematic Transaction : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x35200b82efb00ee6672c240f31cf266c6541d6de2bf2e5542db54697c0ad26a3
You can see that this transaction takes approximately 0.14 Matic for deploying the ERC721 token contract on Mumbai .

Normal Transaction :
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x51567ff12b30cb1a152f84c990a0ceff76bf805fe48f20bfcf9bb73aedd3d076
This transaction takes 0.0009 Matic for the same contract deployment using hardhat . But here , the deployment was done using account private key stored in in hardhat config .

What is the problem in the hardhat deployment script above which is leading to 10x in transaction cost ?

**Edit 1 ->**

[image]

[image]

[image]

contract 1 deployed at : 0x3655A9b3D2825f7039d821a9B27e2d5550445AFf ( tx hash : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x27c8d3673321f4d20282a051bd8fbeeb2470b113f9b88196e52b5bc0fd91d554 )

contract 2 deployed at : 0xd71bc06202AA85d671605C005e3d936F4d7F1433 ( tx hash : https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x4dcfc6f832eb9d35f2075e52652f5a263936646a5a701784fa6d2a7ba944fe64 )

These 2 transactions have 22 seconds gap between them , how can gas price change this much within 22 seconds ? Something is wrong in the deployment script . What is it ?